# Why this Javascript code does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

I am learning Javascript language and so I am on a project while I came across this issue. Here is the code:

```js
function koko() {
  items = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var pos = 0; pos < items.length; pos++) {
    this.items[pos].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(pos);
    });
  }
}

koko();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every time I click on any item with `a` tag I get same value on the console that is `items.length`. But I am expecting it to print the position/index of the element that is clicked. For example, if I click `Click me 2` it should print `1`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thanks sir. I am already reading this :)

Answer (score 0):

When the click listener is executed, `pos` has the value of 3, your code is fine, look at this example:

```js
function koko() {
  items = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var pos = 0; pos < items.length; pos++) {
    this.items[pos].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
    });
  }
}

koko();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```When the click listener is executed, pos has the value of 3``` Can you please explain how is it happening? I mean pos is changing inside the for loop right?

Comment: Yes it is, but javascript doesn't save the value that `pos` had when the function was declared. It gets the value of `pos` when the function is executed, and by that time your variable has already finished the for loop and has kept the value of 3.

Comment: This answer doesn't really fix the problem, as the OP wants to write the number "1", "2", or "3". Your answer writes "Click me " as well.

Comment: @LukeSheltraw you're right, I answered the question "What am I missing here", but didn't give a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the desired results

```js
function koko() {
  items = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var pos = 0; pos < items.length; pos++) {
    this.items[pos].id = pos;
    this.items[pos].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    });
  }
}

koko();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#">Click me 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do note that ID values shouldn't be just numbers. Maybe use a data-attribute parameter instead for real world use

Comment: This helped me clear the confusion. Thanks :)

Comment: Lmao, I wrote almost the same thing right as you posted this.

Comment: Posting code alone is not very useful. Your answer would be much more helpful to visitors if you explained the problem and your solution.

Comment: @FelixKling I would have just have been repeating the comments from rbock's post before my answer he had already established that the value of `pos` wasn't being carried into the function. You are right however, I'll try to be more descriptive in future.

Answer (score 0):

You function logs `pos`, WHEN the button is clicked, not when the event listener is added. To fix this, you can use this code:

```js
function koko() {
  items = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var pos = 0; pos < items.length; pos++) {
    this.items[pos].addEventListener("click", function() {console.log(this.id);});
 }
}

koko();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#" id="1">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="2">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="3">Click me 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The changes it makes from the original code:
Added `id` to each link. The number in this is written to the screen.
Changed Javascript to write the `id` of the link.